# How to set Image.Source property with Dispatcher?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, dispatcher

I tried use this recomendations: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870.aspx ("Handling a Blocking Operation with a Background Thread").

This is my code:

```cs
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ;
        }

        private void Process()
        {
            // some code creating BitmapSource thresholdedImage

            ThreadStart start = () =>
            {
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                    System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                    new Action<ImageSource>(Update),
                    thresholdedImage);
            };
            Thread nt = new Thread(start);
            nt.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            nt.Start();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            button1.IsEnabled = false;
            button1.Content = "Processing...";

            Action action = new Action(Process);
            action.BeginInvoke(null, null);
        }

        private void Update(ImageSource source)
        {
            this.image1.Source = source; // ! this line throw exception

            this.button1.IsEnabled = true; // this line works
            this.button1.Content = "Process"; // this line works
        }
    }
```

In marked line it throws InvalidOperationException "due to the calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.". But application works if I remove this line.

```
XAML:
<!-- language: xaml -->
    <Window x:Class="BlackZonesRemover.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:my="clr-namespace:BlackZonesRemover"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="800" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Border Background="LightBlue">
                <Image Name="image1" Stretch="Uniform" />
            </Border>
            <Button Content="Button" Grid.Row="1" Height="23" Name="button1" Width="75" Margin="10" Click="button1_Click" />
        </Grid>
    </Window>
```

What difference between Image.Source property and Button.IsEnabled and Button.Content properties? What can I do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Specific advice:** `thresholdImage` is being created on a background thread. Either create it on the UI thread, or freeze it once it has been created.

**General advice:** The difference is that `ImageSource` is a `DependencyObject` so it has thread affinity. Therefore, you need to create the `ImageSource` on the same thread as the `Image` to which you're assigning it (ie. the UI thread), or you need to [`Freeze()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms557735.aspx) the `ImageSource` once you've created it, thus allowing any thread to access it.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is because `thresholdedImage` is created in the background thread and used on UI thread.

Calling Freeze method might help. See 
[Updating an Image UI property from a BackgroundWorker thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703617/updating-an-image-ui-property-from-a-backgroundworker-thread)